# How can I confirm that I am using the "full build" of Vue?

Tags: vue.js, browserify, package.json

I have added this line to my package.json as recommended by the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds) (I'm using Browserify):

```
"browser": {
  "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
},
```

But how can I tell this is actually having the intended effect?

Whether or not I have that line, this test does not produce an error:

```
new Vue({
  template: '<div>{{ hi }}</div>'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string template does not throw any error, then you have the "full" Vue version (i.e. it includes the compiler).
You can double check by testing for the presence of [`Vue.compile`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile).

Example with UMD, full build:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div>{{ hi }}</div>',
  data: {
    hi: 'hello'
  }
});

console.log(Vue.compile);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Same but with runtime-only build (no compiler):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div>{{ hi }}</div>',
  data: {
    hi: 'hello'
  }
});

console.log(Vue.compile);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.runtime.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Should you want to test the runtime-only version (i.e. your string template would no longer work), you can try the browserify configuration:

```json
"browser": {
  "vue": "vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the simple test for `Vue.compile` is what I'm looking for!